# Difficult geometry Olympiad symmedian problem

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, contest-math, triangles, problem-solving

I have been training for math olympiads for some time now. I came across this geometry problem from the Italian math book "Giochi Matematici Russi" by Boris A. Kordemsky:

> *Let ABC be an acute - angled triangle. Let m<sub>1</sub> and
> m<sub>2</sub> be the perpendicular bisectors of sides BC and AC
> respectively, moreover let M be the midpoint of side AB. Now we mark
> the interesection points of the median CM and m<sub>1</sub> and
> m<sub>2</sub> as S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub> respectively. The
> lines AS<sub>2</sub> and BS<sub>1</sub> intersect at point K.  Prove
> that ∡ACK = ∡MCB.*

The first thing I did was to plot the question in geogebra.(link will be provided at the end of the article)
After playing around for a while, I had the idea to plot the reflection point of K upon the angle bisector at C. That point K' always seems to lie on the median CM. So after searching the Internet a bit, I found that K seems to lie on a line called the symmedian.(For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmedian) So now the question is to prove that K lies on the symmedian. And this is where I am not able to make any further progress. I thank anybody who can give some advice or hints.

Geogebra link: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/qbn8jzbc .

Yours,
MathGuy :))

Comment: Where is this in Kordemsky's book? I have the English version, and the problems there are much more basic.

Comment: @darijgrinberg hmm, weird. I'm pretty sure it was there in the Italian version.  I don't own the book anymore, but as far as I can remember, it was there.

Comment: @darijgrinberg If it really is not mentioned in the book, I will edit the question. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Also posted to (but closed on) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429450/geometry-olympiad-symmedian-problem

Comment: Aha. Bundeswettbewerb Mathematik (Germany) 2022, 2nd round, problem 3. Too late to be of relevance (official solutions are [already posted](https://www.mathe-wettbewerbe.de/fileadmin/Mathe-Wettbewerbe/Bundeswettbewerb_Mathematik/Dokumente/Aufgaben_und_Loesungen_BWM/loes_22_2_v.pdf)), but yeah, something was really wrong about that reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C'$ be the reflection of $C$ about $M$. There is a unique point $L$ such that the triangle $CAL$ is similar to the triangle $CC'B$ with the same orientation.

Then you can prove that the triangle $CLB$ is similar to the triangle $CAC'$ with the same orientation.

It follows from the two pairs of similar triangles that $\angle CAL=\angle CC'B=\angle C'CA=\angle S_2AC$ and $\angle CBL=\angle CC'A=\angle C'CB=\angle CBS_1$. The two imply that $K=L$, and thus $\angle ACK=\angle C'CB=\angle MCB$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The solution is actually much simpler than I thought.